# one view two controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My app got installation controller and address controller.

```
Address has_one :installation and Installation belongs_to :address
```

In my installation view, I got a simple_form inside in other simple_form. Like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @installation, class: 'form-horizontal' do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>

        <%= f.simple_fields_for @installation.address do |u| %>
              <%= u.label :street_address, label: t('address.address_label'), required: true, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
                <%= u.input_field :street_address, class: 'form-control'
                %>
```

So how I can update the two models ?

Can I have two def params ? Likes this:

```
def installation_params
    params.require(:installation).permit(x)
end

def installation_address_params
    params.require(:????).permit(y)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

Untested, but roughly:

Model:

```
class Installation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

And in your `InstallationsController`:

```
params.require(:installation).permit(...,
  address_attributes: [:id, ...])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Last question, what is the best way to update the 2 models ? Can I do this ? 
 `def update
    respond_to do |format|
if @installation.update(installation_params) && @installation.address.update(installation_params)`

Comment: With nested attributes Rails will save the `Address` when the `Installation` is saved, so you'll only need the `if @installation.update(installation_params)`, not the second condition.

Comment: When I update forms from Installation the model installation change but when I update forms from Address the model dont update.
I dont receive any error

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "update forms from Address". Could you post your controller (on something like http://dpaste.com/), including the `params.require`... statement?

Comment: I put `binding.pry` before  `if @installation.update(installation_params)` and I got this:
http://imgur.com/XlZWCoC

Thank you!

Comment: I change the name of `address_attributes: [:id, ...])` to `address: [:id, ...]`.
I got this: http://imgur.com/5DCrOBv but now I have this error:
"ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch at /installations/61
Address(#70141620807160) expected, got ActionController::Parameters(#70141545974820)"